# Where did the intercept go? Difference between using Anova to evaluate models built from glmer.nb and glm.nb

Tags: r, glm

I conducted a study to assess the effects of chemical treatments on the behavior of insects. This study was conducted in two different years and the design of the study varied somewhat slightly:

- Year 1, I sampled the response of insects to chemical treatments across 5 intervals of time (=date).
- Year 2, I sampled the response of insects to chemical treatments across 4 intervals of time, but replicated the experiment 4x (=replicate) within each interval.

I have been building a series of generalized linear models with the negative binomial family (best distribution for my dataset) to analyze if insects were attracted to different chemical treatments. I am using these models because they allow me to incorporate date and replicate as part of the model as fixed or random effects, and are more likely to detect effects than the Friedman Test, which is typically used to analyze data like mine.

For the data from Year 1, I am using generalized linear models to analyze my data with the following formula:

```
modelYear1 = glm.nb(insect.of.interest ~ treatment + date, data = data)
```

I am then using Anova to analyze if the fixed effects in my model are significant and receiving the following output:

```
Anova(modelYear1, type = 3)

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III tests)

Response: insect.of.interest
          LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
treatment   9.0489  5   0.107131   
date       17.5317  4   0.001523 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This output differs from what is returned if I analyze my Year 2 data. For my year 2 data I am using a generalized linear mixed model so that I can incorporate replicate as a random effect according to the following model (this is the best model for my dataset):

```
modelYear2 = glmer.nb(insect.of.interest ~ treatment + date + (1 | replicate), data = data)
```

Using Anova to analyze if the fixed effects in my model are significant returns a somewhat different output:

```
Anova(modelYear2, type = 3)

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: insect.of.interest
              Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)  2.2228  1     0.1360    
treatment    6.5543  4     0.1614    
date        67.9646  3  1.164e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My major question is...where did the intercept go? Why does Anova report the intercept for my glmer.nb model, but not my glm.nb model? For my work, I would like to report the fixed effects of all my models, regardless of whether they were found to have significant effects or not. Models with significant parameters will then have their estimates reported from the summary() function. The summary function reports estimates for the intercept, but I'd to be able to show these outputs prior to reporting the output of summary.

I'd appreciate any suggestions as to how to solve this problem. Is something fundamentally different going on when I use Anova to look at fixed effects of glms vs. glmms?

Comment: did you try `modelYear1$coefficients[1]`?. Sometimes `intercept` is not printed but you have it in the model coefficients. or summary(modelYear1)?

Comment: Where does the `Anova` function come from?